# Canonical approach to experimenting with a gearbox design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I'm hoping to design a simple gearbox for a 1-seater car for kids. So far I'm only using discs of paper I cut out and rotating them by hand. I wonder what the canonical approach is to prototyping/experimenting with gearboxes. I guess the prototype won't need to be big, but just 10CM or so?

Should it be done virtually in a CAD software instead?

I'm very new so any tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In designing a gearbox the first step is to work out the ratios you need in the context of the torques and rotational speeds you need, bearing in mind that other parts of the drive train such as the differential and wheel diameter will also effect the final drive ratio.  This will allow you to select the most appropriate overall design and specify parts which can meet these requirements.

These basic parameters are simple enough to calculate in themselves but need to be considered in the context of the whole design as they depend on the overall performance requirements for the car. In particular the range of gear ratios required will depend on the mass of the car and the performance of the engine/motor.

For something like this designing gears from scratch is probably not something you want to do so this will likely be a case of sourcing component eg. gears, shafts bearings etc.

The next step is to start thinking about how the whole thing will be packaged which also needs to consider how the gearbox casing relates to other parts of the system. Here a lot depends on what you want to achieve and there are many potential different solutions. I'm assuming that a car for kids will be relatively low speed and power and so potential solutions could include chain and pulley drives as well as gears.

It is also well worth considering whether there is some existing off the shelf component which can be adapted to meet your needs.

To expand on my reply to the first comment. A gearbox is a case where you really need to get quite a lot of the design parameters calculated on paper before you think about prototyping. They key parameters like the ratios and loads on individual parts are largely defined by external factors such as engine characteristics and desired vehicle performance so at the very least you need to give yourself a reasonable starting point.

These parameters are reasonably easy to calculate and don't require FEA or calculus, especially if you are using off the shelf components. It's also entirely reasonable to do most of the design of a gearbox 'on paper' and a working prototype would normally only be needed for things like reliability testing.

Prototyping is most useful for working out fine detail like how the gearbox housing is physically connected to other parts of the vehicle in terms of its size, shape and where mounting points need to go and whether it interferes with other parts. But you can't even begin to do this until you have worked out the basic parameters.

These should be based on your best estimate of things like vehicle weight and engine performance as well as desired top speed and acceleration.

Comment: How about for a new gear design, e.g., a planetary gear, what's a good way to experimenting that?

Comment: It depends what you want to learn by experimenting. If you just want to get a feel for how gearboxes work then something like lego or meccano is good as you have a wide range of ready made gears with a quick and convenient assembly method. In terms of prototyping a real world design a gearbox is something where all of the basic parameters can be calculated fairly easily on paper and until you know these you are just guessing as they are largely defined by other factors in the overall design and a gearbox can be designed with good confidence that it will work as expected.